# Why is I/O operation reading JSON file bottom to top?

Tags: android, json, io

I am reading a stored JSON file from the internal storage of my tablet using the following code:

```
  private String ReadFromLocal() {

        File path =  context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
        File file = new File(path, "abc.json");

        String ret = "No Data";
        try {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
            ret = convertStreamToString(fin);
            //Make sure you close all streams.
            fin.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ret;
    }




public String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.replace(0, 2, line);
        }
        reader.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

The file is successfully detected and read as well, but it read the data from bottom to top instead of top to bottom. This is the original json, read correctly from assets:

```
{
  "0" : {
    "workDetailsList" : {
      "0" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 1",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 1,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 1,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "1" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 2",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 2,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 1,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "2" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 3",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 3,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 1,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "3" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 4",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 4,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 1,
        "allotted" : false
      }
    },
    "category" : "NA",
    "itemHeader" : "Customer Voice 1",
    "totalWorks" : 4,
    "CustomerVoiceSerial" : 1,
    "customerVoiceSerial" : 1
  },
  "1" : {
    "workDetailsList" : {
      "0" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 1",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 1,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 2,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "1" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 2",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 2,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 2,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "2" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 3",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 3,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 2,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "3" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 4",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 4,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 2,
        "allotted" : false
      }
    },
    "category" : "NA",
    "itemHeader" : "Customer Voice 2",
    "totalWorks" : 4,
    "CustomerVoiceSerial" : 2,
    "customerVoiceSerial" : 2
  },
  "2" : {
    "workDetailsList" : {
      "0" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 1",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 1,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 3,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "1" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 2",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 2,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 3,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "2" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 3",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 3,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 3,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "3" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 4",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 4,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 3,
        "allotted" : false
      }
    },
    "category" : "NA",
    "itemHeader" : "Customer Voice 3",
    "totalWorks" : 4,
    "CustomerVoiceSerial" : 3,
    "customerVoiceSerial" : 3
  },
  "3" : {
    "workDetailsList" : {
      "0" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 1",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 1,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 4,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "1" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 2",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 2,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 4,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "2" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 3",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 3,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 4,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "3" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 4",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 4,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 4,
        "allotted" : false
      }
    },
    "category" : "NA",
    "itemHeader" : "Customer Voice 4",
    "totalWorks" : 4,
    "CustomerVoiceSerial" : 4,
    "customerVoiceSerial" : 4
  },
  "4" : {
    "workDetailsList" : {
      "0" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 1",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 1,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 5,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "1" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 2",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 2,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 5,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "2" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 3",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 3,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 5,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "3" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 4",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 4,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 5,
        "allotted" : false
      }
    },
    "category" : "NA",
    "itemHeader" : "Customer Voice 5",
    "totalWorks" : 4,
    "CustomerVoiceSerial" : 5,
    "customerVoiceSerial" : 5
  },
  "5" : {
    "workDetailsList" : {
      "0" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 1",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 1,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 6,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "1" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 2",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 2,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 6,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "2" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 3",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 3,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 6,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "3" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 4",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 4,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 6,
        "allotted" : false
      }
    },
    "category" : "NA",
    "itemHeader" : "Customer Voice 6",
    "totalWorks" : 4,
    "CustomerVoiceSerial" : 6,
    "customerVoiceSerial" : 6
  },
  "6" : {
    "workDetailsList" : {
      "0" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 1",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 1,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 7,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "1" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 2",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 2,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 7,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "2" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 3",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 3,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 7,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "3" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 4",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 4,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 7,
        "allotted" : false
      }
    },
    "category" : "NA",
    "itemHeader" : "Customer Voice 7",
    "totalWorks" : 4,
    "CustomerVoiceSerial" : 7,
    "customerVoiceSerial" : 7
  },
  "7" : {
    "workDetailsList" : {
      "0" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 1",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 1,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 8,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "1" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 2",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 2,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 8,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "2" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 3",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 3,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 8,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "3" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 4",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 4,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 8,
        "allotted" : false
      }
    },
    "category" : "NA",
    "itemHeader" : "Customer Voice 8",
    "totalWorks" : 4,
    "CustomerVoiceSerial" : 8,
    "customerVoiceSerial" : 8
  },
  "8" : {
    "workDetailsList" : {
      "0" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 1",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 1,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 9,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "1" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 2",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 2,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 9,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "2" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 3",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 3,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 9,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "3" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 4",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 4,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 9,
        "allotted" : false
      }
    },
    "category" : "NA",
    "itemHeader" : "Customer Voice 9",
    "totalWorks" : 4,
    "CustomerVoiceSerial" : 9,
    "customerVoiceSerial" : 9
  },
  "9" : {
    "workDetailsList" : {
      "0" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 1",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 1,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 10,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "1" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 2",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 2,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 10,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "2" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 3",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 3,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 10,
        "allotted" : false
      },
      "3" : {
        "workTitle" : "Work 4",
        "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",
        "timeRequired" : "0/60",
        "selected" : false,
        "workSerial" : 4,
        "parentListItemPosition" : 10,
        "allotted" : false
      }
    },
    "category" : "NA",
    "itemHeader" : "Customer Voice 10",
    "totalWorks" : 4,
    "CustomerVoiceSerial" : 10,
    "customerVoiceSerial" : 10
  }
}
```

But with the described code, this is the string I get:

}}  "customerVoiceSerial" : 10  "CustomerVoiceSerial" : 10,  "totalWorks" : 4,  `"itemHeader" : "Customer Voice 10",  "category" : "NA",  },    }      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 10,      "workSerial" : 4,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 4",    "3" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 10,      "workSerial" : 3,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 3",    "2" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 10,      "workSerial" : 2,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 2",    "1" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 10,      "workSerial" : 1,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 1",    "0" : {  "workDetailsList" : {"9" : {},  "customerVoiceSerial" : 9  "CustomerVoiceSerial" : 9,  "totalWorks" : 4,  "itemHeader" : "Customer Voice 9",  "category" : "NA",  },    }      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 9,      "workSerial" : 4,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 4",    "3" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 9,      "workSerial" : 3,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 3",    "2" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 9,      "workSerial" : 2,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 2",    "1" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 9,      "workSerial" : 1,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 1",    "0" : {  "workDetailsList" : {"8" : {},  "customerVoiceSerial" : 8  "CustomerVoiceSerial" : 8,  "totalWorks" : 4,  "itemHeader" : "Customer Voice 8",  "category" : "NA",  },    }      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 8,      "workSerial" : 4,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 4",    "3" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 8,      "workSerial" : 3,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 3",    "2" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 8,      "workSerial" : 2,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 2",    "1" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 8,      "workSerial" : 1,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 1",    "0" : {  "workDetailsList" : {"7" : {},  "customerVoiceSerial" : 7  "CustomerVoiceSerial" : 7,  "totalWorks" : 4,  "itemHeader" : "Customer Voice 7",  "category" : "NA",  },    }      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 7,      "workSerial" : 4,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 4",    "3" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 7,      "workSerial" : 3,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 3",    "2" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 7,      "workSerial" : 2,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 2",    "1" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 7,      "workSerial" : 1,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 1",    "0" : {  "workDetailsList" : {"6" : {},  "customerVoiceSerial" : 6  "CustomerVoiceSerial" : 6,  "totalWorks" : 4,  "itemHeader" : "Customer Voice 6",  "category" : "NA",  },    }      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 6,      "workSerial" : 4,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 4",    "3" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 6,      "workSerial" : 3,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 3",    "2" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 6,      "workSerial" : 2,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 2",    "1" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 6,      "workSerial" : 1,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 1",    "0" : {  "workDetailsList" : {"5" : {},  "customerVoiceSerial" : 5  "CustomerVoiceSerial" : 5,  "totalWorks" : 4,  "itemHeader" : "Customer Voice 5",  "category" : "NA",  },    }      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 5,      "workSerial" : 4,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 4",    "3" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 5,      "workSerial" : 3,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 3",    "2" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 5,      "workSerial" : 2,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 2",    "1" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 5,      "workSerial" : 1,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 1",    "0" : {  "workDetailsList" : {"4" : {},  "customerVoiceSerial" : 4  "CustomerVoiceSerial" : 4,  "totalWorks" : 4,  "itemHeader" : "Customer Voice 4",  "category" : "NA",  },    }      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 4,      "workSerial" : 4,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 4",    "3" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 4,      "workSerial" : 3,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 3",    "2" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 4,      "workSerial" : 2,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 2",    "1" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 4,      "workSerial" : 1,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 1",    "0" : {  "workDetailsList" : {"3" : {},  "customerVoiceSerial" : 3  "CustomerVoiceSerial" : 3,  "totalWorks" : 4,  "itemHeader" : "Customer Voice 3",  "category" : "NA",  },    }      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 3,      "workSerial" : 4,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 4",    "3" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 3,      "workSerial" : 3,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 3",    "2" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 3,      "workSerial" : 2,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 2",    "1" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 3,      "workSerial" : 1,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 1",    "0" : {  "workDetailsList" : {"2" : {},  "customerVoiceSerial" : 2  "CustomerVoiceSerial" : 2,  "totalWorks" : 4,  "itemHeader" : "Customer Voice 2",  "category" : "NA",  },    }      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 2,      "workSerial" : 4,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 4",    "3" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 2,      "workSerial" : 3,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 3",    "2" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 2,      "workSerial" : 2,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 2",    "1" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 2,      "workSerial" : 1,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 1",    "0" : {  "workDetailsList" : {"1" : {},  "customerVoiceSerial" : 1  "CustomerVoiceSerial" : 1,  "totalWorks" : 4,  "itemHeader" : "Customer Voice 1",  "category" : "NA",  },    }      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 1,      "workSerial" : 4,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 4",    "3" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 1,      "workSerial" : 3,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 3",    "2" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 1,      "workSerial" : 2,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 2",    "1" : {    },      "allotted" : false      "parentListItemPosition" : 1,      "workSerial" : 1,      "selected" : false,      "timeRequired" : "0/60",      "workStatus" : "NOT ALLOTTED",      "workTitle" : "Work 1",    "0" : {  "workDetailsList" : {"0" : {`

I have used the above mentioned method successfully in the past. I tried searching but couldn't find any such csae. Changed tablet, but doesn't help.

BTW, Android/data/data/... is not the correct path in my case, it is:

Android/data/com.example....... hence the mentioned method in use.

Comment: Where's the source for `convertStreamToString()`?

Comment: @MichaelBurr: added. Oh, I didn't check this code!!! But in my previous application this was working perfectly fine so I copy pasted it simply. Kindly guide ahead. Thanks

Comment: "Oh, I didn't check this code!!!" - big mistake. Have a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#replace-int-int-java.lang.String-

Comment: The problem is `sb.replace(0, 2, line);`.  you probably want something like `sb.append(line)`.  Perhaps with a "\n" also appended depending on if you want newlines from the file in the string or not.

Comment: @Henry: Yes, true. I am debugging it already. Since it worked perfectly well in my previous app, I didn't care to check it here. Even while debugging, this didn't click. Thank you very much. I am slowly trying to analyze the logic flaw

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Thanks a lot Michael, too embarrassing for me. I appreciate your time and concern.